# Http get not getting all data

Tags: java, android, http

I am using the following code to receive data from a web API service.  The problem is, not all the data is getting received.  I have checked using fiddler that all the data is actually being sent, but the program is receiving about 2% of it.

```
    public String getAllTableDataWithBearerToken (String tableName) {

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();        
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(HOST + API_ACCESS_URL + tableName);
    httpGet.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken);
    String responseString; 
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!=200) return "Failed to get table data for table: " + tableName + " with error: " + response.getStatusLine().toString();

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if(entity != null) {
            Log.d("INFO", "There was an entity to read");
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            responseString = convertStreamToString(stream);
            stream.close();

        } else { 
            Log.d("INFO", "No entity received");
            return "No data to get for table: "  + tableName;
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.d("INFO", "Error getting entity data.  Error is: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "ClientProtocolException getting data for table: "  + tableName + " with error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("INFO", "Error getting entity data.  Error is: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "IOException getting data for table: "  + tableName + " with error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
```

and the inputstream converter function is :

```
    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("INFO", "Error reading input stream.  Error is: ");
       e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("INFO", "Error closing input stream.  Error is: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Log.d("INFO", "Returning read data: " + sb.toString());;

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of String you are reading in, but you could be hitting the Get size limit
[maximum length of HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

try sending it as a Post, to see if that will fix the issue.

If not, then it will require some more stack traces and some printouts to see what you are receiving.

Comment: Hi.  It's not the get request, but the get response that is getting truncated.  I will try to do some more analysis, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the problem was the logging of the response - it has a maximum.  When I wrote the last 500 characters of the stream - it was indeed the last 500 characters of the stream.